# Understanding the body decorator in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, nest-api

Where is the object that references the @body payload stored?

If your user controller has a post function.

> @Post() @HttpCode(HttpStatus.CREATED) create(@Body() user: IUserBase):
>   Promise { return this.usersService.create(user); }

Where is the user variable stored?
Is it stored in the request object of the nest.js server?

Answer (score 3):

It is injected into the function as an argument.

The `@body` decorator basically says:
Please cast the json that arrives in the request body into `IUserBase` type and place it as a parameter to this controller's handler.